# How to add only odd numbers inside an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, integer

I would like to get the sum of only the odd numbers stored in array and it shall pass as argument to the function. Here is my code:

```py
def sum_odd(arr):
    sum = 0
    for i in arr:
        if(i%2==1):
            sum+=i
    return(arr)

nums = (input("Enter 10 numbers: "))
arr = list(map(int, nums.split()))

print("The sum of all odd numbers is: ", sum_odd)
```

but when I print it only says:

> The sum of all odd numbers is:  <function sum_odd at 0x0000025BE2A37F70>

I would also like to try to input an error message if the user inputs beyond 10 numbers.

Comment: You should pass an argument to your function `sum_odd`

Comment: You're not calling `sum_odd`.

Comment: Put `print("The sum of all odd numbers is: ", sum_odd(arr))`

Comment: `sum` is Python builtin, so try not to use it as program variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should give your function an argument when you call it
Second, inside your function you're returning the array not the result.
I changed your code and here it is:

```
def sum_odd(arr):
    ans = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i%2 == 1:     # if it's odd. 
            ans += i     # keep adding up
    return ans

arr  = [int(x) for x in input("Enter 10 numbers: ").split()]

print("The sum of all odd numbers is: ", sum_odd(arr))
```

Input:

```
Enter 10 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

output:

```
The sum of all odd numbers is:  25
```

Comment: Try not to use builtin `sum` as variable name.

Comment: I will do this way - `Generator Expression`:  `return sum(x for x in A if x%2)` - in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following two things.

1. The `sum_add` function needs to be called. That is, change `sum_add` to `sum_add(arr)`

```py
print("The sum of all odd numbers is: ", sum_odd(arr))
```

2. `sum_add` function is returning the array itself instead of the sum. Please change from `return(arr)` to `return(sum)`

These changes should solve the issues here